# RSS Feed consuming issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, proxy, rss, connection, feed

While consuming RSS feed in the our company domain, i am getting proxy connection problem. how to solve this.. can any one give exact example which is working in corporate domain.

```
WebRequest MyRssRequest = WebRequest.Create("csharp-dotnet-interview-questions.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/…;); 
WebResponse MyRssResponse = MyRssRequest.GetResponse(); 
Stream MyRssStream = MyRssResponse.GetResponseStream(); 
// Load previously created XML Document XmlDocument MyRssDocument = new XmlDocument();
```

Comment: it is related to program related only..

Comment: Are you trying to create an ASP.NET app that reads an RSS feed, but the company network is making things difficult for you? Can you provide some more information: What have you tried so far? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: if i am using below code.. i am getting The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. exception                                                                   WebRequest MyRssRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://csharp-dotnet-interview-questions.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
        WebResponse MyRssResponse = MyRssRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream MyRssStream = MyRssResponse.GetResponseStream();
        // Load previously created XML Document
        XmlDocument MyRssDocument = new XmlDocument();

Comment: I took the liberty of adding your code snippet to the question itself. Did you see this question, some of the answers deals with setting the proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490177/how-do-i-determine-elegantly-if-proxy-authentication-is-required-in-c-sharp-wi

Comment: yes i got the solution. i have posted in by blog. http://csharp-dotnet-interview-questions.blogspot.com/2011/11/reading-rss-feeds-in-aspnet-with-proxy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [WebProxy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx), I think it's what you're looking for... :)